# functions that intake objects belonging to classes in other files

Tags: c++

Why if I have

in foo.h:

```
class Foo
{

}

void Bar(const Foo& foo);
```

it works but:

in foo.h:

```
class Foo
{

}
```

in bar.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

void Bar(const Foo& foo);
```

doesn't work (unknown type name 'Foo' is its exact words)?

I don't know what about my question isn't specific and forward declarations don't work they just create a error 'duplicate symbol' so im just going to post the code im working with
in creatures.h

```
    #ifndef CREATURES_H_
    #define CREATURES_H_
    #include <string>
    #include "textio.hpp"

    class Creature {
    private:

    protected:
        int statBlock[10];
    public:
        std::string name = "foo";
        Creature ();
        void ai(int);
    };

    class Dwarf : public Creature {
    private:

    public:
        std::string name = "Dwarf";
        Dwarf (int);
        void defaultDwarfGen();

    };
```

main.cpp

```
    #endif
    #include "creatures.hpp"
    #include "textio.hpp"
    #include <iostream>

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
       Dwarf creature_1(0);

       return 0;
    }
```

textio.hpp:

```
#ifndef TEXTIO_H
#define  TEXTIO_H
#include <iostream>
#include "creatures.hpp"


void challenge(const Creature& param);


#endif
```

Comment: _"doesn't work?"_ - Can you provide us with a less vague description of the problem. Simply telling us it doesn't work is pointless - try including the complete error messages generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are including `textio.hpp` in `creatures.hpp` so first time that compiler see function `void challenge(const Creature& param)`Creature class isn't defined.

When you include `createures.hpp`in `textio.hpp` `CREATURES_H_`  is already defined  and bypass inclusion)

You can fix it deleting this include or declaring a forward definition for Creature class

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer this question properly, you must provide foo.h, foo.cpp, **bar.h**, and bar.cpp

In short:
To make use of Bar in foo.h, foo.h must have the declaration for Bar.
To make use of Foo in bar.h, bar.h must have the declaration for Foo.

To make use of Bar in foo.cpp, foo.h or foo.cpp must have the declaration for Bar.
To make use of Foo in bar.cpp, bar.h or bar.cpp must have the declaration for Foo.

When I say, "must have declaration for", you can #include the appropriate header.

If you are trying to use Foo in Bar and Bar in Foo, then you've got a circular reference. The way we overcome this is with a forward declaration.

You can read about forward declarations here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/misc-technical-issues#forward-decl